# fraction of value gets increased each time

Tags: java, android

**// Grams to Pounds and Ounces**

```
public static String convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces(String grams) {
    double weightInKG = Double.parseDouble(grams) / 1000;
    double pounds = weightInKG / 0.45359237;
    double lbs = Math.floor(pounds);
    double fraction = (pounds - lbs) * 16;
    return String.valueOf(Math.round(lbs) + "lbs" + " " + String.format("%.1f", new BigDecimal(fraction)) + "oz");
}
```

**// Pounds and Ounces to Grams**

```
public static double convertPoundsToGrams(String pounds, String oz) {
    double lbs = 0;
    double ounces = 0;
    double grams = 0;
    try {
        if (pounds != null && pounds.trim().length() != 0) {
            lbs = Double.parseDouble(pounds);
        }
        if (oz != null && oz.trim().length() != 0) {
            ounces = Double.parseDouble(oz) * 0.062500;
        }
        grams = (lbs + ounces) / 0.0022046;
        return grams;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.err.println("Invalid input.");
    }
    return grams;
}
```

I try to convert the pounds and ounces to grams and display the same pounds and ounces by converting grams.

I enter 1 lbs and 0.9 ounces which gets converted back to grams, but when i convert the grams back to pounds and ounces i get 1 lbs and 1.1 pounds... [`0.2 ounces is getting increased each time`]

Comment: There is a floating point division issue I keep coming across in Java. I would recommend using the [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead and doing all the math using the methods provided by it. Seems to be a lot more reliable.

Comment: I am unable to recreate the problem using the code you provided. How are you converting the double returned from `convertPoundsToGrams` to the String required in `convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces`? In other words, do your grams match?

Comment: I am converting the double[which is grams] using // Grams to Pounds and Ounces

Answer (score 1):

`convertPoundsToGrams` returns `double` value. To get back the grams to Pounds and ounce, you should change the type of returned gram (double) value into type of `String` because `convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces` have parameter of `String`.

try this:

```
double grams = convertPoundsToGrams("1", "0.9"); 
System.out.println(grams);
String grams2PO = String.valueOf(grams);
System.out.println(convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces(grams2PO));
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
double grams = convertPoundsToGrams("1", "0.9");
Log.d(TAG, "Grams: " + grams);
Log.d(TAG, "String grams:" + String.valueOf(grams));
String pounds = convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces(String.valueOf(grams));
Log.d(TAG, "Pound/Oz string: " + pounds);
```

The String returned is "1lbs 0.9oz".

I guess something is going wrong with how you are converting/passing the result of `convertPoundsToGrams` (which returns a double) to `convertGramsToPoundsAndOunces`, which takes a String.